# Data Modelling multiple table of same type into a single table to aggregate all the table into one single table

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-relationship, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have a question regarding data modelling. Suppose I have following tables 3 student tables. Source_table1 contains A_ID as primary key and  Name as an attribute. Source_table2 has B_ID as Primary key and Name & Address as other attributes.Source_table3 has C_ID as Primary key and Name, Address and Age as attributes. If we want to create a new table as Student Master with all the records in that table, how can we do that? If we are creating a cross reference table then how should we approach that problem?

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. Does all these tables keep data about the same entities?

Comment: what you want to do is unclear.  We understand that you want to consolidate the tables, but do you want to maintain the old primary keys, do you want to use 1 of the 3 as the point of consolidation???  You have an image of your source tables perhaps provide an example of what you want to accomplish as well

Comment: You have data about students in the table. These tables are coming from different sources. Student details can be present in multiple tables or it could be present in only one. Old key can be maintained or a new key can be used. I need to make a student master table that holds unique records. No duplicate records must be present. As all the tables have diiferent keys, but they might point to the same record that the other table is also using different key. So how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating data from different sources is complicated. In the end, you want to end up with something like:

```
student (student_id PK, name, address, source1_id, source2_id, source3_id)
```

However, there are some issues to resolve to get there.

**Identity**

How will you identify matching records in the different sources? It looks like your sources use surrogate identifiers, but those have no meaning outside the context of the source databases. What you're looking for is a suitable natural key. The only common denominator among the sources is a student's name, but names are notoriously poor identifiers.

It can be useful to actually test the data rather than assume it will or won't work. For example, a query such as:

```
SELECT s1.name, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM student_source_1 s1
INNER JOIN student_source_2 s2 ON s1.name = s2.name
GROUP BY s1.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

repeated for (student_source_2, student_source_3) and (student_source_1, student_source_3) should give you some insight into the size of the problem.

You could match student_source_2 and student_source_3 based on both name and address. That might give better results, or worse if the two sources have different addresses (or spellings thereof) for the same student. That brings us to our second concern:

**Inconsistency**

Assuming you can resolve the identity problem, you may need to deal with inconsistent data. What if sources 2 and 3 have different addresses for the same student? How do you determine the correct address?

In some cases, it could be sufficient to just map the sources without resolving inconsistencies.

**Winging it in the real world**

One technique I use on harder cases is to build a mapping table by hand, e.g.

```
student_map (student_id PK, source1_id, source2_id, source3_id)
```

Each of the source_id columns should have a unique constraint, and usually all 3 will be nullable. This is a first step toward the student table above.

I would start by inserting all the perfect 1-to-1 matches, then left join each of the sources with the mapping table to get the unmatched records. Having the unmatched source records side-by-side and sorted makes it easy to visually spot likely matches. It's tedious and error-prone work, but sometimes it must be done regardless. For inconsistencies I might choose the most complete/best looking source as base, and fill in the gaps from the other sources. If you can involve teachers or people who are familiar with the actual students, or present them with alternatives to choose from, by all means do so.

More data can be extremely useful. If the sources have social security numbers, family information, etc, these can be used to match students. I would use any number of queries to find perfect matches among various pieces of information, and insert those into the mapping table, before doing the side-by-side matching.

You may well find that a source has internal consistency problems due to poor design - e.g. multiple records for the same student. This may require fixing the source data before continuing.

A good understanding of the relational model of data is invaluable for this kind of work, since you'll be identifying candidate keys, following dependencies and encountering anomalies.